# Find days between dates

Tags: postgresql, between, days

I am looking to subtract 2 dates to get the number of days in between.  However, the columns are defined as "timestamp without time zone".   I'm not sure how to get a whole integer.

I have a stored procedure with this code:

```
v_days_between_changes := DATE_PATH('day',CURRENT_DATE - v_prev_rec.date_updated)::integer;
```

But I get this error:

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

QUERY:  SELECT DATE_PATH('day',CURRENT_DATE - v_prev_rec.date_updated)::integer

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the difference between the dates, which returns an interval. Then, extract the number of days from this interval.

```
WITH src(dt1,dt2) AS (select '1/1/2019'::timestamp without time zone, CURRENT_DATE ) 
select EXTRACT(day FROM dt2-dt1) nbdays
from src;
 nbdays
-----------
        98
```